# Why does MYSQL convert NULL or String values to 0 when comparing against int value?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, comparison

Why when comparing a NULL value to an INT in MYSQL, MYSQL convert's NULL to '0'?  I lost hours of sleep and debugging due to this horrible mishap on behalf of MYSQL.

**EDIT**

Example:  I get a value from post input from client, if that input is NOT SET, i have to set that field as NULL because if I set as 0 or any other int value, I might be hitting an actual record in the db.  AND if set it to any other NON-INT value, MYSQL converts it to 0 when comparing.

Comment: have you tested `null safe comparison` operator? I mean `<=>` instead of `=`?

Comment: Without an actual code example we can't be sure, but according to the [manual][1], a mathematical operation involving NULL should always result in NULL and a logical operation involving NULL should always treat NULL as "false" or INT 0.  Can you give us a code example?


  [1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: @JBH your right, and please read my EDIT. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You [cannot use relational operators with NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html). The only operators that work with NULL are IS NULL and IS NOT NULL.

If comparing with `null safe comparison operator` against `INT` either isn't a good fit for your case, You'd have to include a separate check for `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is genuinely a special kind of value.

If you have a column with an `int` datatype called `column`, then

```
     `column` = NULL
```

*never* comes back true, even for rows in which the `column` is set to `NULL`. Neither does

```
      `column` <> NULL
```

ever come back true for columns that don't contain nulls. If you want to look for nulls, you need to use `IS NULL`.

In MySQL, coercing (implicitly casting) a string to an integer interprets any leading digits as if they were an integer. But if `NULL` is involved, the result is also `NULL`. So,

```
select 0 + 'abcde', 0 + '99abced', 0+NULL
```

gives the integer values `0`, `99`, NULL as results.